# Concatenating pandas dataframes of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have several empty dataframes, all of different lengths, they all share some common fields, but each dataframe has some unique columns as well. In trying to concatenate them I keep getting a `ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned`.

```
cols1 = ['Test', 'Col1', 'Col2']
cols2 = ['Test', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Date']
cols3 = ['Test', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Time']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols3)

df_dict = {'project': [df1, df2, df3]}
for table, dfs in df_dict.items():
    result = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Ideally my output should have a columns list that looks like this:

```
['Test1', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Date', 'Time']
```

Is there any way to get past this **without** using `Merge`. I don't want to use `Merge` because I won't always know the columns that are shared, etc...

Comment: pd.concat(df_list )

Comment: @Wen-Ben I edited my question, forgot to include that the dfs are already in a list within a dict.

Comment: You still can using `concat`